# Product of positive definite matrix and matrix symmetrization

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

Suppose $X$ and $A+A^*$ are positive definite matrices. I would like to ask if it is true that $AX+ (AX)^* = AX + XA^*$ is also positive definite?

Comment: Is X a Hermitian matrix? You are taking (AX)* = XA*.

Comment: Yes as inherited from the meaning of positive definite ness, and the entries and real.

Comment: Is A also real?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a counterexample: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\ -2&1\end{pmatrix},\quad X=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\ 1&2\end{pmatrix}$$